# Disable and empty model value and then restore it

Tags: angularjs

I have working code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled" >
<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-disabled="disabled">
```

When `disabled == true` the input is disabled. I need to hide actual model value (set empty) as well. And after uncheck the checkbox actual model value should appears. How to do it without changing model value?

Comment: You could use a temporary variable bound in the view and the original variable will be stored in your controller but not on its scope to be bound in the view, when you check the checkbox then you can store the value in the original variable and clear off the text box value and when you uncheck it you can bring back the original value from the variable in your controller. If you want this as a reusable component then you could write a custom directive for it.

Comment: I have a lot of that fields. So I cant handle them one by one.

Comment: You will need a temporary variable for each of your models (you could use an Array or an Object) to keep the values of your models befor voiding them up...

Comment: Logically it is a view issue, not a model. So will dig in this direction. May be some manipulation with view value...

Comment: Could you please post the core html structure of your checkboxes along with its container(parent) and inputs along with the array/data source bound to it, maybe a directive could be written to make it more robust and easier to maintain, also the additional info provided will help you get better answers from Stack Overflow

Comment: Have posted my answer. I don't need to modify the actual value, only a view value.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled" ng-change="change()">
<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-disabled="disabled">

...

$scope.change = function() {
  if ($scope.disabled) {
    $scope.textBackup = $scope.text;
    $scope.text = '';
  } else {
    $scope.text = $scope.textBackup;
  }
};
```

*Note: I posted before reading @AbdulMateenMohammed comment... My answer is an implementation of his suggestion...*

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best option but if you want to deal only with the view:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled">
<div ng-show="disabled">
   <input type="text" ng-init="text2 = ''" ng-model="text2" ng-disabled="true">
</div>

<div ng-hide="disabled">
   <input type="text" ng-model="text">
</div>
```

Again, this is not the best option!!! MarcosS option is the recommended.

Answer (score 0):

@Makarov Sergey, I think even when you have a complex view or data source the basic idea is to use a temporary variable because you need to have two values b/w which you swap around.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var originalText = '';
    var vm = this;
    vm.text = 'Hello, World!';
    vm.onValueChanged = onValueChanged;    
    
    function onValueChanged(text) {
      if (vm.disabled) {
       originalText = text;
        vm.text = '';
      } else {
       vm.text = originalText;
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <em>I </em><span>&hearts; </span><em>AngularJS</em>
</div>

<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.disabled" ng-change="ctrl.onValueChanged(ctrl.text)"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.text" ng-disabled="ctrl.disabled"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tip: For the objects that aren't displayed in the view but present in the controller shouldn't be assigned on the scope because using scope would add some JavaScript events to do the data-binding which is unnecessary overhead such as the dirty check event for the two-way data-binding so that's why in the sample code snippet I used `var originalText = '';` instead of `vm.originalText = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution that works for me atm

```
function directive() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            let oldViewValue = '';
            scope.$watch(() => attrs.hideValue, (newV) => {
                if (newV == 'true') {
                    oldViewValue = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
                    ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = '';
                } else {
                    ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = oldViewValue;
                }
                ngModelCtrl.$render();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And use:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled" >
<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-disabled="disabled" hide-value="disabled">
```